# Mirror symmetry for polarized abelian surfaces and Shioda-Inose K3s

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties, k3-surfaces, mirror-symmetry

It is well known (cf. Dolgachev) that there is a beautiful notion of mirror symmetry for lattice-polarized K3 surfaces. That is, if we are given a rank $r$ lattice $M$ of signature $(1, r - 1)$ and a primitive embedding $\iota : M \to Pic(S)$ that contains a pseudo-ample class, we call $S$ an $M$-polarized K3 surface.

Mirror symmetry for this case essentially comes from splitting $H^2(S)$ into $M$ and (in a certain sense) an orthogonal complement, which yields a mirror K3 which is $M^\vee$-polarized for a certain lattice $M^\vee$ of rank $20 - r$.

**Q1:** Is there a similar story for abelian surfaces?

We have another construction that we can produce from abelian surfaces. Given an abelian surface $A$ with Picard rank $r$, there is a canonically associated K3 surface (see, e.g.,  "Modular Invariants for Lattice Polarized K3 Surfaces", A. Clinger and C. Doran), the Shioda-Inose K3 $SI(A)$ whose Picard rank is $ 16 + r$ (this K3 is birational to a double cover of $Km(A)$, the Kummer surface of $A$). The nice fact about this K3 is that it is Hodge-theoretically isomorphic to $A$.

So let's start with our abelian surface $A$. Assuming the answer to the first question is positive, then we have a mirror abelian surface $A^\vee$ whose Picard rank is $4 - r$. We also have the chain of relationships
$$
A \leadsto SI(A) \leadsto SI(A)^\vee
$$
which also has Picard rank $4 - r$.

**Q2:** Again, assuming a positive answer to the first question, is there some relationship between $A^\vee$ and $SI(A)^\vee$? The latter is obviously not the Shioda-Inose K3 of $A^\vee$ since its Picard rank is too small. But is there some other relationship there?

Comment: I have no answer for your question, but, is there any related argument for Enrique surfaces?

Comment: Have you looked at the paper of Kapustin and Orlov? arXiv:hep-th/0010293 "Vertex Algebras, Mirror Symmetry, And D-Branes: The Case Of Complex Tori"

Comment: >Mohanmmad Enriques surface is the same as a $U\oplus E_8(-1)$-polarized K3 surface, so I think it is self-mirror symmetric (Pic never changes). These is also a PhD thesis on the subject (E. Lakuriqi, U Penn).